No add field in watched/ignored tags dialog, when too many tags are visible
When you open the watched/ignored tags dialog for managing the watched/ignored tags, the input field for adding new tags is not displayed, when there are too many tags being displayed. The dialog will look like this:

As you see the input field is not displayed anymore, since the is no room to display it. Also, all the other tags are missing as well. There should be a scrollarea where the tags are being displayed, so the add new tag input field is always visible.
